# Better way to check multiple variables equal a single value in Python

Tags: python, syntax

In Python I want to check the following:

```
if x is None and y is None and z is None and ...
```

I'd rather say something like:

```
if x, y, z is None:
```

But that's not valid syntax. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to make sure all expressions satisfy a condition.  The Python builtin `all` is made precisely for that.  Since we have no need to introduce a new variable name, here I'll use the name `_`, which is a valid Python name and is the convention for a "throw-away" variable.

```
all(_ is None for _ in (x,y,z))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about falsy-ness (which is often the case):

```
if not all((x, y, z)): ...
```

Comment: did you mean "if not any((x,y,z)):"